# Reference about solutions of $\Delta f = V f$ or $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\partial_i f= V f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

Let $V\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$.
I have been growing an interest about equations of the form:

1. Find $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$
   $$\quad \quad  \sum_{i=1}^n c_i(x)\partial_i f(x)= V(x) f(x) .$$
   where $c_i\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ not all zero.
2. Find $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$
   $$\quad \quad  \Delta f(x) = V(x) f(x) .$$

**I'm curious about what solutions look like (e.g. are symmetric if $V$ is symmetric?) and if there are general principles/techniques to express the solution.**
For example, if $n=1$ and $c_1$ constant then equation (1) becomes $\partial_t f(t) = V(t)f(t)$ and a solution is given by $f(t) =f(0)e^{\int_0^tV(\tau)d\tau}$. Similarly if $V\equiv 0$ then the equation (2) becomes $\Delta f \equiv 0$ which can be approached using Fourier and we have integral kernels (e.g. Poisson) to express $f$ in terms of its values on a sphere.

It would be nice if these things would extend with some modifications to the case $n\neq 1$ or $V\neq 0$ .

I guess that these equations have been studied extensively. Can somebody point me to a good, precise reference? (Or just write an answer if you know it.)

*Edit*: following the comment of psz2Z, we do have a general technique to study the solutions of (1), the method of characteristics.
Consider a curve $\gamma:I\to \mathbb R^n$ such that $\frac d{dt}\gamma(t) = (c_1(\gamma(t)), \dots, c_n(\gamma(t))$, then the solution $f$ along $\gamma$ must satisfy the ODE
$$\frac d {dt}f(\gamma(t)) = V(\gamma(t)) f(\gamma(t)),$$ thus $f\circ \gamma (t) = f(\gamma(0))e^{\int_0^t V(\gamma(s))ds}$.

Comment: Method of characteristics for the first.

Comment: The second equation is the steady version of the Schrödinger equation, more often written as
$$
(-\Delta+U(x)) f = E\,f
$$
but this is equivalent as yours with $U = V + E$. This is indeed studied a lot. Not all values of $E$ are allowed (i.e. in your case, not all potentials), only the eigenvalues of the Schrödinger operator $-\Delta+U(x)$. Everything is known explicitly when $U(x) = |x|^2$ (that's the quantum harmonic oscillator) or when $U(x) = 1/|x|$ (the Hydrogen atom)

Comment: @LL3.14 how does one find a solution in the two cases you mention? (I'm mostly interested in the case $n>1$). If you feel like writing an answer (even partial) I'd vote it up.